# Fixed div inside fixed scrollable div doesn't stay fixed

Tags: html, css, css-position, fixed

I tried to recreate the problem BUT I wasn't able. -> [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/g36fxtg6/1/) 
Btw, I have an full page menu, that is scrollable on Y. Inside that I placed some images that I want to stay `fixed at top` but them scroll with the scroll of the nav.
Does anyone ever seen this issue?

I'm still trying to recreate on the fiddle the problem but for now there you can see what I want to achieve.

EDIT:
I realize where the problem is-> [NEW FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/g36fxtg6/3/) 
The issue is because of `transform: scale`.

EDIT2 + NEW PROBLEM: 
forget for a sec the main problem, because I'm going to remove the scale animation. Open on a mac + chrome my [first fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g36fxtg6/1/) , it doesn't scroll if the mouse is on the image. Any idea how to solve?

Comment: Is this your problem : https://jsfiddle.net/g36fxtg6/2/ ?

Comment: `position:fixed` is always fixed in relation to the **viewport**. It's really not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: @divy3993 That looks like it.

Comment: If that is your problem, then you might try using position:fixed for img selector in your css

Comment: new info, i recreate the issue in a new fiddle

Comment: Can you post your website url??? ur new js fiddle seems tobe working fine.

Comment: It's still local sorry but It's strange you can see it correctly.. on my pc doesn't work, neither on my mac

Comment: @dghez Actually when you move your cursor on image and try to scroll, so it must not scroll. That is browsers interaction features

Answer (score 1):

The problem, you see, is `transform: scale`

Comment: I know, I wrote in the question because I realized that :)

Comment: I know I am just feeling loopy today, haha

Answer (score 1):

I think this might help you:

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/g36fxtg6/4/)

**CSS**

```
.long{
    width: 60%;
    background: grey;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow-y: scroll; /* Added */
    height:100%; /* Added */
}
```

**Removed overflow-y:scroll; from nav selector in css**

Comment: @dghez if still issues just tell me.

Comment: yup, but on windows there is the scrollbar visible :/

Comment: check new info / problem